# Why Kotlin not have treeSet and treeMap collections?

Tags: kotlin

I am not able to find treeSet and treeMap implementation in Kotlin.
Studio is also not detecting those collection.

Is there any alternative for these two in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [sortedSetOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-set-of.html) and [sortedMapOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-map-of.html).

Comment: These are only available on the JVM, not JS or Native.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Kotlin implementation. You can use any util from Java stdlib directly in your Kotlin code:

```
val map = TreeMap<String, String>()
val set = TreeSet<String>()
```

Comment: Okay.. but why kotlin not provided like val x = linkedMapOf<Int,Int>(). it has implemention of Hashmap and linkedhashmap but why treemap is missing

Comment: I don't expect they double the whole java stdlib. I'm not sure, what was the main reason for having `listOf()` and similar functions, but I see at least some reasons: 1. Providing convenient functions for the most typical cases. 2. Kotlin is multiplatform, so we needed a way to create list/set/map in a generic way. 3. In Kotlin we have immutable collections, but almost all Java collections are mutable, so we needed at least `listOf()`, etc. functions. And then it makes sense to complement them with their mutable counterparts.